# Exporting image file from JDeveloper

Tags: sql, oracle, jdeveloper

Sounds trivial, but the "publish" option is nowhere to be found.

This is what I get when right clicking the diagram

[image: right click on diagram result]

And the build menu doesn't allow to export an image either

[image: Build menu (no publish option)]

Using ***`Jdeveloper 12.1.3`***

Any clue most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clever me...

In case it could help someone else: Go to Diagram -> publish diagram

Voilà.